# Verifying linearity of mappings from from P to P

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to get a better handle on thinking about vector spaces in a more general sense (really want to drop the "arrow in $\Bbb R^n$" idea of vectors), and so I'm trying to verify that the mapping: $$T: P_n \to P_n$$ where $P_n$ is the space of polynomials of at most degree n, given by $$Tp(t) = p(2t+3)$$ is linear.  This would mean showing that $$T(\alpha p_1(t) + \beta p_2(t)) = \alpha T(p_1(t)) + \beta T(p_2(t)) = \alpha p_1(2t+3) + \beta p_2(2t+3)$$

The problem (and my question) is that my intuition (which sucks) tells me that, by how the mapping is defined, we already have: $$T(\alpha p_1(t) + \beta p_2(t)) =\alpha p_1(2t+3) + \beta p_2(2t+3)$$ by some kind of vague "plug in $2t+3$"-argument.

Another idea that I had was to rewrite the polynomials as general polynomials, i. e.: $$T(\alpha p_1(t) + \beta p_2(t)) = T(\alpha \sum_i a_i t^i + \beta \sum_j b_j t^j)$$
But that seems to lead no where, I'm stuck with the same vague "plug in"-argument.
What is the proper, rigorous way to reason about these things?

EDIT: Fixed typo

Comment: You haven't told us what $P$ is, but I'm assuming it is polynomials. Is it all polynomials of any degree?

Comment: Yes, precisely! Fixed! :)

Comment: Technically, it should be polynomials of degree at most $n$...

Comment: Technicality, but fixed it anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic operations on the polinomials are defined as $$(aP+bQ)(x):=aP(x)+bQ(x)$$
what you want to show is that $$T((aP+bQ)(x))=aT(P(x))+bT(Q(x))$$
which can be obtained by
$$\begin{align}T((aP+bQ)(x))&=(aP+bQ)(2x+3)\\
&=aP(2x+3)+bQ(2x+3)\\
&=aT(P(x))+bT(Q(x))
\end{align}$$

Comment: Aaaa OK! I've had a bit of a misconception regarding what I was trying to show, it seems! This clears it up! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can proceed from your general polynomials idea:
$
\begin{align}
T(\alpha p_1(t) + \beta p_2(t)) &=T(\alpha \sum_{i=0}^n a_i t^i + \beta \sum_{i=0}^n b_i t^i)
\\&= T(\sum_{i=0}^n (\alpha a_i+\beta b_i) t^i)
\\&=\sum_{i=0}^n (\alpha a_i+\beta b_i) (2t+3)^i
\\&=\alpha \sum_{i=0}^n a_i (2t+3)^i + \beta \sum_{i=0}^n b_i (2t+3)^i
\\&=\alpha T(p_1)+\beta T(p_2)
\end{align}
$

Comment: Why cant I accept several answers as "best answers"? This is also nice cause it never uses that (aP+bQ)(x) = aP(x) + bQ(x), which is maybe faster, but certainly feels a bit like cheating :)